# ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine()) equals 0, but ST_Disjoint = True

Tags: postgis

Recently, I encountered a very strange phenomenon. I have to split a multilinestring on the point of touching another line, sounds complicated but it is just preprocessing to build a graph.

Now the problem is - I calculate the shortest line to the MultiLineString(). I get a linestring now I take the point which is supposed to be on the MultiLineString(). But according to PostGIS it is spatialy disjoint! calculating the length to the MultiLineString() the result is 0.

Where does this Problem come from?

Comment: It may come from rounding errors in computing. Snapping to grid usually helps http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_SnapToGrid.htm.

Comment: I is a rounding error for sure! But it shouldn't effect the result imho. Is there a common solution? - http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html indicates the distance below 0.00001m

Comment: That tolerance is for geography. As far as I know there is no tolerance at all for geometry if SnapToGrid is not used.

Answer (score 3):

Could be a classic double precision floating point "*normal issue*".

Check this page about tolerance in Postgis:
https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/ToleranceDiscussion

Verify also the validity of geometries. ([ST_IsValid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html))